# How to get variable in CGI made by /bin/sh + Apache

Tags: apache, shell, cgi

I'm coding following CGI script

```
echo "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n"
echo "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>title</TITLE></HEAD>"
echo "<BODY>"
echo "<FORM ACTION="http://exapmle.com/page2.cgi" NAME="PAGE1" METHOD="POST">"
echo "input:<INPUT TYPE=text NAME="data1" SIZE=10 MAXLENGTH=10>"
echo "<INPUT TYPE=submit NAME=nbtn VALUE='GO TO PAGE2'>"
echo "</FORM>"
echo "</BODY>"
echo "</HTML>"
```

How to get valiable in CGI made by /bin/sh + Apache
I am glad gime me sample cord

Answer (score 2):

In the CGI script, you receive it as a parameter to *main*, so it should be in some place pointed by *argv*

Apache runs the cgi just like you:

```
script.cgi var1
```

And the parameters are in *argv*, so this:

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

Will output

```
var1
```